# Cannot append user to group

Tags: linux, command-line, fedora, useradd

I'm having trouble adding a user to a group:

```
# useradd -aG group user
# useradd -a -G group user
# useradd -G group user --append
```

It tells me that the `-a` option is an invalid or unrecognized.

Can someone help me add the user to a second group (and not make him belong to it as the primary group)?

Using Fedora 36. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useradd` command is for adding a new user account. The `usermod` command is for modifying an existing user account - for example by adding it to a group

```
usermod -aG group user
```